# Comparing two lists in scheme

Tags: scheme, racket

I am trying to recursively compare and output the smallest number in 2 equal sized set of lists. Example `(testFunc '(3 5 9) '(1 2 11))` will return `'(1 2 9)`. I have tried the following:

```
(define (testFunc X Z)
  (if (< (car X) (car Z)) ((car X) (testFunc((cdr X) (cdr Z))))
    ((car Z) (testFunc((cdr X) (cdr Z))))))
```

My thought process and what I am trying to achieve:

compare the first element of X and Z. If x(1) is smaller than z(1) then print x(1) and drop the first element from both lists using cdr and repeat the process by calling `testFunc` else print z(1) and do the same thing until we went through each position.

Appreciate all the help in advance. Thanks!

Comment: If you drop first elements of both lists you could be losing a value that is still minor than those in the current lists. For example say you have `'(79 8 44) '(81 32 7)`. By following that process you'll get `'(79 8 7)` whilst the correct answer being `'(32 8 7)`.

Answer (score 2):

To call `testFunc`, you must use `(testFunc arg1 arg2)`. You must **not** use `(testFunc(arg1 arg2))`. Scheme is parenthesis-sensitive; you must not add (or remove) extra parentheses.

Likewise, to bunch up the results, you need to use `(cons item rest)`, and not just `(item rest)`.

---

Have you considered using just `(map min list1 list2)`?

Comment: can you give an example please

Comment: @user3610137 Sure. For example, use `(cons (car X) (testFunc (cdr X) (cdr Z)))`.

Comment: can I do (cdr (testFunc X Z)) in my case?

Comment: Re: "Have you considered using just (map min list1 list2)?" Can't use map/min. That's why I'm doing it one by one by doing the first element of each list, using cdr to drop the first element, and redoing the process. if that makes sense.

Comment: @user3610137 On Stack Overflow, we are supposed to turn a blind eye as to whether questions are for coding puzzles or homework or what not. That means that I write answers the way a professional programmer would solve the problem. "Can't use map/min" is irrelevant to that aim; to a professional programmer, basic language functionality is definitely not out-of-bounds.

Comment: @user3610137 As for whether you can do `(cdr (testFunc X Z))`, it's syntactically valid, but you'll find that you'll be doing infinite recursion.... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the k-minor numbers from 2 lists where k is the size of both lists. There are many ways to do this.

Here's one idea:

1. First `append` both lists.
2. Then `sort` them from lower to higher.
3. Then `take` the first three.

But that wouldn't be exactly recursive (sort is recursive but the procedure as such is not).

So another idea uses tail recursion using a list that saves the returning result and we'll name it `res` and a procedure that gets the minor item from a list called min-list.

1. Check if `length` of `res` is `k`. If so, return `res`.
2. Otherwise `let minorA= (min-list A), minorB=(min-list B)`

Finally:

```
if minorA < minor B
recursive call with A=(remove minorA A) B=B, res=(cons minorA res), k=k
else recursive vall with A=A B=(remove minorB B), res=(cons minorB res), k=k
```

And this idea is in fact recursive.

I got the code written but I want you to try and code it yourself so please tell us of any doubt.

Happy coding!

**EDIT**:
I've read the comments and it seems you can't use `min`. Does this mean you cannot use the one that comes in `racket/base`? If so, you can write your own procedure to check which is the minimal value but if you're not allowed even that, then we'll have to try something else. (I'll post here next idea when I get one).

Oh, and please, clarify the form of the input lists, are they ordered from minor to greater? In your example it seems that way but if it's not always like that then the procedure can change a bit.